# Finally called before subscribe has processed all messages

Tags: system.reactive

I have written a subject that I use to push out messages that I receive from RabbitMQ.

I was expecting to always receive all messages on subscribe before finally is triggered but I am usually not receiving all messages and can see that that subscribe is called after finally is called.

```
_messageSummarySubject = new Subject<MessageSummary>();
_subscriber = _messageSummarySubject
    .Finally(Finisehd)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .SubscribeOn(Bootstrapper.Resolve<ISchedulerService>().DispatcherScheduler)
    .ObserveOn(Bootstrapper.Resolve<ISchedulerService>().DispatcherScheduler)
    .Subscribe(
        x =>
        {
            //This is sometime called after finally
        });
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(s => SomeAction(_messageSummarySubject));
```

SomeAction is basically calling

subject.OnNext(messageSummary);

a few times in a thread and once the thread is closed calling subject.OnCompleted();

Is this the correct behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The line `//This is sometime called after finally` should be being called before `.Finally`, unless there's a massive delay with your `Bootstrapper.Resolve<ISchedulerService>().DispatcherScheduler`.

Comment: The order seems to be imported I tried to move down Finally from the beginning to before Subscribe and everything is now working as expected.

Comment: Yes, the order is important. Each step in the pipeline effectively is a small observable - and each one responds to the `.OnCompleted` in the order in which they are defined in the pipeline. It seems that your `.ObserveOn` is changing threads, allowing the `.Finally` to finish before the values do in the `Subscribe`. If it were all happening on the one thread then it would be in the correct order - which is what you've done by putting the `.Finally` after the `.ObserveOn`.